# Merge statement that allows insertion of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, merge

I have two tables,

Table 1

```
Id         | medicineName
-------------------------
1          | benalgin
2          | xanax
3          | xanax
-------------------------
```

And I have this second table, where I need to insert the ID from the above table into the second table (which has null values in the medicineId column), and I need to use MERGE statement that will allow me to insert duplicates.

Table 2

```
medicineId | medicine
-------------------------
   null    | xanax
   null    | xanax
   null    | operil
-------------------------
```

I have tried this, but since I need to have duplicate records with different ID, I get the error:

> cannot insert or update duplicate rows

```
MERGE table2 b
  USING table1 a
    ON (a.MedicineName = b.Medicine and a.Id is null)
    when matched
    then update set
    a.Id = b.MedicineId;
```

Comment: Please tag the question with the database that you are using.

Comment: When 2 `id`s available for a given `medecine`, which one do you want to pick? Eg for xanax, do you want 2 or 3?

Comment: Also, why do you specifically want to use `merge`? It is meant to update or insert, while you seem to only need update.

Comment: hey @GMB I want to insert the 2 and 3 for the two XANAX rows. Is there any way to merge two tables and allow for duplicates? tnx

Comment: I have maybe 100 rows of data in each table.. that is why I want to use merge, if you think I can use Update or Insert to insert/update rows of data at once, I would like to know it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you do need two queries for this.

First `update` the existing records in `table2` with one of the `id`s coming from `table1`:

```
update table2
set medicineId = (
    select min(id) from table1 t1 where t1.medicineName = table2.medicine
)
```

Then `insert` the missing records:

```
insert into table2 (medicineId, medicine)
select id, medicineName 
from table1 t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.medicineId = t1.id and t2.medicine = t1.medicineName
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0ae8cdf2eff0dfeab827f0416e931f29)**

Table content after update:

```
MEDICINEID | MEDICINE
:--------- | :-------
2          | xanax   
2          | xanax   
null       | operil
```

Table content after insert:

```
MEDICINEID | MEDICINE
:--------- | :-------
2          | xanax   
2          | xanax   
null       | operil  
3          | xanax   
1          | benalgin
```

Comment: hmm, I think I get what you are talking about, but I need this code for SQL.. this does not work for me at the moment. :/ Or maybe I am doing something wrong? (I am talking about the update query)

Comment: @eligible_net: what does *does not work* mean? Are you getting an error message, which one exactly?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 't2'. Reffering to this part  => 'update table2 t2'

Comment: @eligible_net:  ok, so back to one of my original questions: which database are you using?

Comment: @eligible_net: ok, I updated my answer with a solution that uses SQLServer syntax.